# EJB Injection in Application Client don't work

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi

I tried inject a stateless `EJB` in my application client and I get the following error

> SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app : Unable to load the EJB module. DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB. Check the archive to ensure correct packaging for C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\EJB.
>
> If you use EJB component annotations to define the EJB, and an ejb or web deployment descriptor is also used, please make sure that the deployment descriptor references a Java EE 5 or higher version schema, and that the metadata-complete attribute is not set to true, so the component annotations can be processed as expected

My client is defined thus:

```
@EJB
private static Sless sless;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Sless says: " + sless.hello());
}
```

The class `Sless` is my interface which is defined thus:

```
@Remote
public interface Sless {
    public String hello();
}
```

I also have a class implementing `Sless`

```
@Stateless
public class SlessBean implements Sless{
    @Override
    public String hello() {
        return "hello, world!\n";
    }    
}
```

Any help as to where the problem is coming from would be appreciated.

Comment: You're running a console application. EJB's can only be injected on enterprise applications that run on a Java EE compliant server like GlassFish 3 and JBoss 7 e.g. inject the EJB in a Servlet in a Web Application.

Comment: The application in an Enterprise application (client though) running on glassfish 3.1.2.2.

Comment: The client is not running it as an Enterprise application.

Comment: The error which i pasted above is the server log, so i think it is actually running on the server.

Answer (score 4):

**1)** `Standalone clients` or `non-managed POJOs`(POJOs which are not maintained by Containers) do not support annotation injection. So `@EJB` will not work.

**2)** You will have to do a *manual* `JNDI look up` from your standalone client.

**What you need for this ?**

**1)** Your *EJB* extending `Remote` interface. Because `Local` interface does not expose `EJB` to ***Cross Application*** or ***Remote*** calls.

**2)** Dependency `jar` files in your standalone client. **ie:** `ORB Jar`

**3)** You will need to know `RMI/IIOP` port on your server.

**4)** You will also have to take care if `Standalone client` and `Server` use different **JDK/JRE implementations.**  **For ex:** 1 using `SUN JDK` and other using `IBM JDK`.

**Follow this for connecting to `EJB` on Glassfish from a `Standalone client`** >> https://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB

Comment: IMO it would be better to consume the EJB's methods using web services  instead of doing RMI calls, but that will depend on OP's design.

Comment: I have gone through this blog already but nothing different happened

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, hmmmm, for that, he will need to expose EJB as web service.

Comment: @Luiggi that is also an option but i just really want to try out the EJB annotation and see how it works. Thats all

Comment: @Ayodeji, what part you don't understand in that document ? Did you try doing it ?

Comment: @Luigi Thanks for your time though *taking a bow*. I actually made it work but i think their is an issue with my IDE or so, i deleted the application.xml file, then i realised its trying to access a file that doesn't exist (the executable .jar file) because when it was created (the .jar file), the name it gave it was different from the one its trying to access.

Comment: @Ravi, a part of it then i was lost when i was to do steps 4 and 5. More so, the whole Foo thing is really confusing me *covers face*

Comment: @Ayodeji, `FooEJB` is your EJB's mapped JNDI name in server. :)

Comment: Does that mean its the class implementing the interface.

Comment: @Ravi what could make my IDE create an executable with one name and trying to run it with another name. That's the problem i am facing now. I have been able to by pass the whole lookup problem

Comment: @Ayodeji, `FOO` is the *remote* interface extended by your EJB class. So it is casting received EJB object to `FOO` *interface*.

Comment: @Ayodeji, executable with one name and running with another ? Check your IDE' run configuration.

Comment: Where in the configuration do i check. I am using netbeans 7.3

Comment: Right click your project in the project explorer. It should be there